# How many Partitions can we have in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a requirement in my IoT project like, a custom java application called "NorthBound" (NB) can manage 3000 devices maximum. Devices send data to SouthBound (SB - Java Application), SB sends data to Kafka and from Kafka, NB consume the messages.
    To manage around 100K devices, I am planning to start multiple instances (around 35) of NorthBound, but i want same instance should receive the messages from same devices. e.g. Device1 is sending data to NB_instance1, Device2 is sending data to NB_instance2 etc.

To handle this, i am thinking of creating 35 partitions of same topic (Device-Messages) so that each NB instance can consume one partition and same device's data should go to same NB instance. Is it the right approach? Or is there any better way?

How many partitions can we make in a Kafka cluster? and What is a recommended value considering 3 nodes (Brokers) in a cluster? 
Currently, we have only 1 node in Kafka. Can we continue with single node and 35 partitions?

Say on startup I might have only 5-6K devices, then I will have only 2 partitions with 2 NB instances. Gradually when we add more devices, we will keep adding more partitions and NB instances. Can we do it without restarting Kafka? Is it possible to create partitions dynamically?

Regards,

Krishan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can imagine the number of partitions you can have depends on a number of factors.

Assuming you have recent hardware, since Kafka 1.1, you can have 1000s of partitions per broker. Moreover Kafka has been tested with over 100000 partitions in a cluster. [Link 1](https://www.confluent.io/blog/apache-kafka-supports-200k-partitions-per-cluster)

As a rule of thumb, it's recommended to over partition a bit in order to allow future growth in traffic/usage. Kafka allows to [add partitions at runtime](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_modify_topic) but that will change partitioning of keyed messages which can be an issue depending on your use case.

Finally, it's not recommended to run a single broker for production workloads as if it was to crash or fail, you'd be exposed to an outage and possibly data loss. It's best to at least have 2 of them with a replication factor of 2 even with only 35 partitions.